# C++ function problem,

Tags: c++

I have this code, but when I compile it with Borland Turbo C++, Turbo C++ say:

> Error filename.cpp 13: Call of  nonfunction in function main()

my code is:

```
 #include <iostream.h>
 int reload (int yes, int no) {
    int reload;
        cout << yes << no;
        cin >> reload;

    return reload;
 }

 main () {
    int a, reload = 1;
    while (reload == 1) {
        reload (1,0);
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> a;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Where did you get that horrible, non-compliant "C++" code? `main()`, seriously? If it's from a book, burn or bury it immediately, it will only teach you terrible habits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int a, av = 1, reload = 1;
```

You named a variable `reload` which hides the `reload()` function. The compiler thinks you are trying to "call" the `int reload` variable, thus "call of nonfunction".

Rename either the function or the variable.

Comment: Alternatively you can use ::reload()

Answer (score 1):

You have a `int` **reload** variable in main that hides the **reload** function. You don't *overload* resolution between variables and functions only between different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a local variable and a function with the same name `reload`

Answer (score 0):

You have a local variable in `main` called `reload` which hides the function. Rename your local variable and you should be fine